Vibration in vehicle from 20-50 mph, lessens with speed. Doing a tire- rebalance didn't fix it. Could it be an alignment issue?
06 Camry.
Neighbor's car.
Vibration less noticeable above 50.

No, it's not an alignment issue.  Check the wheels (rims) before anything else.
